# Overriding Django's reset password email templates

Tags: python, django, email, templates

In my Django app, I would like to customise the email sent to users when they request a password reset. I have these templates saved in my **project's** `templates` directory.

- `/templates/email/password_reset/password_reset.html` for HTML email
- `/templates/email/password_reset/password_reset.txt` for plain email
- `/templates/email/password_reset/password_reset_subject.txt` for the subject

In my URL Patterns, I have...

```
urlpatterns = [

...

    url('^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset,
        {
            'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password.html',
            'email_template_name': 'email/password_reset/password_reset.txt',
            'html_email_template_name': 'email/password_reset/password_reset.html',
            'subject_template_name': 'email/password_reset/password_reset_subject.txt'
        },
        name='password_reset'),

...

]
```

However, Django still sends emails using the default password reset templates. Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, but.. If you pass params with equal sign ?email_template_name'='email/password_reset/password_reset.txt'

Comment: @avs Thanks for your comment. I think the url() function takes the name of a function and a list of keyword arguments as a dictionary, so it's not necessary to use the equals sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, I had accidentally defined `auth_views.password_reset` twice in my URLs. Removing the duplicate fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as that ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#url)).

```
url('^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset,
    {
        'template_name': 'accounts/reset_password.html',
        'email_template_name': 'email/password_reset/password_reset.txt',
        'html_email_template_name': 'email/password_reset/password_reset.html',
        'subject_template_name': 'email/password_reset/password_reset_subject.txt'
    },
    name='password_reset'),
```

Comment: Hi @marksweb, thanks for your answer. I don't think it's necessary to use the kwargs name since I'm passing it as the third argument, so Python knows what I'm referring to even without having to name it. Django respects the 'template_name' but nothing else, so it must be getting the dictionary of arguments through?

Comment: @Kieran yeah, so be honest I've looked in to it & you're right. If you've matched the template names, like it seems you have, it should work.